# String after split

Tags: arrays

I want to find out what to put inside ??? 
So for example I want to create an array with the same number of elements in the String

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String strIn) {
    strIn = strIn.toLowerCase();
    strIn = strIn.trim();
    String str2 = strIn;
    str2.split("");
    String[] word = new String[ ????];




    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I provided the code. I think it is java programming

Comment: use `String tmp[]=str2.split("\\W+");`  `String[] word = new String[tmp.length] ;`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
String input = "your string input";
String[] inputArray = input.split(" ");
String[] word = new String[inputArray.length];
```

Comment: that will not work if there are multipe spaces between the words. better use regex \s+

Comment: second table is "empty", remember